# Dropdownchecboxes selected value validation in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a `DropDownCheckBoxes` where I can CHECK multiple items from the list. Now what I want is,

A validation on button click for multiple Items selected must be from the **same month** if the selected items are not from the same month then it should prompt an alert message for selecting the items as for same month.

For ex:- If first selected item from the list is of `April` then the user has to select the next item from April only, if other month selected than it should throw an alert message.

Here is the screenshot of my `DropDownCheckBoxes`

[![`DropDownCheckBoxes`][1]][1]

Below is my code which I tried first for getting `selected value` of the list but got an error as

> Line: 13
>   Error: 'options' is null or not an object

See the js fiddle for my code **[HERE][2]**

kindly suggest what is wrong and how to **validate** the user on `button click` for the same.

Comment: You are using a custom select, in which you show a `div` with multiple options. These are not the `option` elements from a `select` tag, causing the error "options is null or not an object".

Comment: @Jorrex: so what should be _done_ particluar for this ?

Comment: First of all, try formatting your HTML ;) It's easier to read and see the structure instead of one block of text.

Comment: @Jorrex: See the updated fiddle, is that what you wanted ?

Comment: @Jorrex: what happened ?? did you got what u wanted ? or I need to make some more formattion ?

Comment: Trying to implement Freak's idea.

Comment: @Jorrex: OK try and let me know.. I am going for lunch, will be back in 15-20 mins. BRB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I took a look at your code. And since I didn't know it you wanted it in plain Javascript or jQuery, I took the liberty of doing it in jQuery (since it's easier).

Also I don't know the true purpose of your code, so I based it upon your example and the information you gave us. This might give you an idea on how to complete your task.

Either run the snippet below or take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/vt9nqddp/).

```js
/* Slide open menu and change arrow direction */
$("#caption").click(function() {
    $("#cmbEmp_Name_dv").slideToggle();
    $("#down, #up").toggle();
});

/* On change disable all checkboxes from different months */
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    var amountChecked = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length;
    if (amountChecked === 1) {
        var month = getMonth($(this).next().html());
        $("input[type='checkbox']").each(function() {
            var myMonth = getMonth($(this).next().html());
            if (month !== myMonth) {
                $(this).prop("disabled", true);
                $(this).next().css("background-color", "gray");
            }
        });
    }

    if (amountChecked === 0)
        $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("disabled", false).next().css("background-color", "transparent");
});

/* Function to check if all checked options are from the same month */
$("#btnSubmit").click(function() {
    var firstSelected = $("input:checked").first().next().html();
    if (firstSelected !== undefined && firstSelected !== "undefined" && firstSelected && firstSelected != "") {
        var firstMonth = getMonth(firstSelected);
        var isNotEqual = false;

        $("input:checked").each(function() {
            var month = getMonth($(this).next().html());

            if (firstMonth !== month)
                isNotEqual = true;
        });

        if (isNotEqual)
            alert("Please check items from the month " + firstMonth);
        else
            alert("Validation complete - good to go!");
    }
 else
 {
  alert("Select an option first!");
  $("#cmbEmp_Name_dv").slideDown();
 }
});



/* Function to strip off all characters and return the month */
function getMonth(html) {
    var monthPart = html.split("(").length > 1 ? html.split("(")[1] : "-";
    return monthPart.substr(0, monthPart.indexOf("-")).trim();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="cmbEmp_Name_sl" class="dd_chk_select" style="display:inline-block;position:relative;width:55%;">
    <div id="caption">
 Select <span id="down">&darr;</span><span id="up" style="display: none;">&uarr;</span>
    </div>
    <div id="cmbEmp_Name_dv" class="dd_chk_drop" style="display:none;position:absolute;width:500px;">
        <div id="checks" style="height:45%;">
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_0" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$0" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_0">--Select--</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_1" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$1" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_1">ANIL VITTHAL GAWADE-312(April - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_2" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$2" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_2">ANURADHA A. DESHMUKH-53(April - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_3" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$3" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_3">ASMA SIDDIQUI-83(April - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_4" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$4" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_4">DEEPTI MAITHIL-1250(April - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_5" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$5" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_5">GAURAV JHUNJHUNWALA-2222(March - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_6" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$6" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_6">HITESH PANCHAL-253(April - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_7" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$7" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_7">JAGDISH UBARE-362(April - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_8" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$8" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_8">JAIDEEP MAHAKAL-134(April - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_9" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$9" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_9">JASMINE RATHOD-228(April - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_10" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$10" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_10">JIGAR SHAH-358(April - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_11" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$11" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_11">Junaid Chaudhary-2487(April - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_12" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$12" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_12">KAMAL MATALIA-17(April - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_13" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$13" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_13">KETAN NALAWADE-2478(April - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_14" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$14" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_14">KRUPA DAVE-349(April - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_15" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$15" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_15">NEHA ARUN KHANNA-2145(March - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_16" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$16" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_16">NILESH GAIKWAD-903(March - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_17" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$17" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_17">PALLAVI KATHAL-2465(April - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_18" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$18" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_18">RAMESH  SANAP-1855(March - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_19" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$19" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_19">SAKINA VIVIAN DSILVA-2392(April - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_20" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$20" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_20">SAMANTHA SAXENA-2442(April - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_21" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$21" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_21">SANGEETA JIJI RANE-314(April - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_22" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$22" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_22">SARVESH SUBHASH CHAUDHARY-2462(March - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_23" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$23" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_23">SAYED SOHAIL JAVED AKHTAR-2014(April - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_24" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$24" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_24">SHALIBHADRA HAKANI-2158(April - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_25" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$25" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_25">SONAL RAVINDRA AMBEDE-2533(March - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_26" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$26" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_26">SRINIVAS VENKANNA SAMUDRALA-2525(March - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_27" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$27" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_27">SUNIL DESAI-2484(March - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_28" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$28" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_28">UMANG DARJI-2239(March - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_29" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$29" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_29">UMESH VASHISTH-1900(March - 2016)</label><br />
    
    <input id="cmbEmp_Name_30" type="checkbox" name="cmbEmp_Name$30" />
    <label for="cmbEmp_Name_30">VISHAL SUBHASH PAWADE-1881(March - 2016)</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
&nbsp&nbsp
<input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" value="Process" id="btnSubmit" />
```

**Notice**
I did implement @Freak his suggestion, by disabling all the options different from the user his first choice.

On the other hand, I also implemented the check on the **Validate** button, where as it will check if the user may or may not have checked a different month. Just in case.

Comment: I am, but keep in mind that this is not a chat. These comments are meant for commenting on the matter at hand.

Comment: You should include jQuery script first, otherwise this code won't work.
Also, wrap it in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });` so the code will be executed when the document is ready. And the checkboxes may be dynamically binded, you do have to make sure you have a `div` with `id="cmbEmp_Name_dv"` since the code will search for that element. And if you decide to remove the arrows, you should delete that one line of code: `$("#down, #up").toggle();`

That should do the trick. Most important is including jQuery and wrapping it in `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: and if this is the answer you were searching for, please mark it as "Answer", so other people can learn from this as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109129/discussion-between-coder-and-jorrex).